# uniroot in R won't accept interval

Tags: r

I am running this code:

```
n <- 30
set.seed(42)
x <- rcauchy(n)
minL <- function(x){
  sum(-10*log(pi)-sum(log(1+(x-mu)^2)))
}
uniroot(f=minL,interval=c(-10,10),check.conv = FALSE, maxiter = 1000, trace = 0)
```

and keep getting this error message:

```
Error in uniroot(f = minL, interval = c(-10, 10), check.conv = FALSE,  : 
  f() values at end points not of opposite sign
```

I have tried re-writing and reformatting code (eg lower= -10, upper = 10) but still have the same issue.

Comment: You don't provide `mu`, so I can't reproduce the error. Nevertheless, the error message is clear: when your function `minL` is evaluated at the end points the signs are the same and, consequently, `uniroot` doesn't think there's a root between them. Try changing your interval so that it bounds the root.

Comment: Sorry, mu=0. @lyngbakr

Comment: Try drawing the function between -10 and 10 with mu=0 to see the issue... did you mean to work with its derivative, or did you mean to call `optim` rather than `uniroot`? Perhaps you could explain what you're trying to achieve more clearly.

Comment: Well, it part of question set by a lecturer. Fairly obviously once plotted the distribution does not have a root, but it is one of the tools he asked us to use to find the MLE, not really sure how you would use it for that as it doesn't seem to intuitively find the MLE given it is not designed to find the either the maximum of minimum, but the root. Thus its name I guess.

Comment: It could be used to find a maximum if you apply it to the derivative of the function.